# Multiple Windows user accounts and Git Bash

Tags: git

I am using a colleagues machine whilst they're away for a few months. Let's call their Windows user account `User_A`, and their GIT username `Git_A`. I've created another windows account on the machine, `User_B`, and setup GIT to be `GIT_B`. Git was already installed. But I'm having problems with permissions to `pull` / `push` etc.

I thought I would save myself from generating another key, so I copied my `.ssh` folder off my old machine onto my colleagues. I put this in the usual `C:\Users\User_B\`. On my old machine, I stored all the repos in `C:\Application`. I copied this folder to the same location on my colleague's machine, to save cloning the various repos.

When I try to `pull` I get a permission denied message. No biggie, I'll just generate another key. This new key failed too with the same error:

```
FATAL: R any *branch* *GIT_A* DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from the remote repository.
```

The repo does exist, and my public key has been added. I am logged in as `User_B`, but the error message says `GIT_A`, not `GIT_B`, has been denied. I tried setting the global `user.name` etc, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GIT\.gitconfig` as well as still having these settings in `C:\Users\User_B\.gitconfig` to see if this would solve the problem. But it didn't.

I also noticed that if I type `cd ~` into the GIT Bash, `pwd` is `C:\Users\User_A\`, despite being logged in as `User_B`.

How can I solve these issues? My gut feeling is that the permissions issue is being caused by GIT using `User_A` and `GIT_A`. As a side note, I did reinstall GIT, but the issues remained. I'm also reasonably new to GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `HOME` environment variable was still set to `C:\Users\User_A`. Making sure this pointed to `C:\Users\User_B` solved my issues.